# How can I perform a long task (ie. image scanning) on a thread/background task?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I'm using the EMC Captiva PixTools API to develop an image scanning application.  The API suggests a simple long-running loop to receive images while scanning but that will block the UI thread.

Example:

```
while(true)
{
   Image newImage = Scanner.GetNextImage(); // blocks until image is received
}
```

I'd like to guarantee this executes on a separate thread (not the UI thread) and continues running until the user cancels it.  I also need to return the newImage object back to the main thread so it's added to the UI.

In a Windows Forms application I'd use a BackgroundWorker, but this code is running from a .NET Library (which is then loaded in a Windows Forms app).

I've been trying to understand the async/await pattern but I'm not sure that guarantees anything to be run on a separate thread?

Any suggestions on the best practice to solve this?

Comment: You were on the right track actually.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that async/await does not guarantee threading. Task.Run() does, though. Start with this:

```
await Task.Run(
    () =>
    {
        while(true)
        {
           Image newImage = Scanner.GetNextImage();
           // ImageReceived(newImage); ?
        }
    }
);
```

Or...

```
while (true)
{
    Image newImage = await Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
           return Scanner.GetNextImage();
        }
    }
}
```